# Ghost theme static webpage

Tags: web, static, blogs, ghost

Right now im starting with my own personal blog, im doing this with Ghost, im developing my own theme based on casper, the blog is also my personal site, so i want to have a static page were i can upload all the reveal.js presentations that i've done (myblog.com/talks), like a list of presentations, right now i have my page-talks.hbs on my theme folder, but i wanna know of how can i upload all the static content from reveal.js, is there any way for doing this?
i've tried putting the html files directly inside the themes folder but i get 404 error when trying to access the url.

Answer (score 0):

In ghost to make a static page, there are 2 important steps you should implement. First, you should create a static page on the admin panel (Click to "New Story"). After this, in the "Post Settings Menu" (by clicking on the gear icon in the top right corner) check the box to "Turn this into a static page". Hit 'Publish'.

Second, create a .hbs file manually in your theme folder with a prefix of "page-" and with the name (title) you choosed in the first step, like: page-your-choosed-name.hbs.

By now you should able to reach your static page, and you can easily fill in the hbs file with content.

Hope this helps!